# Pattern Matching and Replacement

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
text_col
---------------
apple, pear
apple/orange, pear~pear|pear
kiwi banana
pear\kiwi
```

I want to change all `pear` in this column to `watermelon`.

All I can think of is to `select` all the rows that have `pear`, and `update` `pear` to `watermelon` one by one.

Is there a better/cleaner way to do it?

I am trying to create a plpgsql trigger function to achieve this.

Comment: Cleaner way than update statement? Can you include your `update`?

Comment: @Parado I thought I have to `select` all the rows that contains `pear` by using `like`, and `loop`, `replace` the selection, and `update`. But @danihp has much cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [replace](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) function?

**Function**

> replace(string text, from text, to text)

**Description**

> Replace all occurrences in string of substring from with substring to

**Sample**

> replace('abcdefabcdef', 'cd', 'XX')    abXXefabXXef

For your code is a **simple update**:

```
Update table T set text_col = replace( text_col, 'pear', 'watermelon' );
```

**Updated** due Igor Romanchenko suggestion:

```
Update table T 
set text_col = replace( text_col, 'pear', 'watermelon' )
where text_col like '%pear%';
```

Comment: Your answer is so much simpler than my though. Thanks.

Comment: It might be more efficient to limit the update query only to rows, that actually have `pear` in text.

Answer (score 0):

Select replace(text_col,'pear','watermelon') from tablename